# Regex matching URL's by sub-folder

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I am trying to essentially write an outbound URL matcher so I can replace a stream of html containing URL's to point to my CDN. I cant use the IIS URL Rewrite module as I am using compression. I currently have a regex that matches on a sub folder for a specific file type i.e.

```
Regex ASSET_PATH = new Regex(@"(?i)assets/([A-Za-z0-9\-_/.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff|png|gif|js|css|mov|mp4|ogg|avi|mp3)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

This works great and allows me to manipulate anything in the string from that point onwards ( i.e. from "assets/" onwards to the right ). What I need to achieve is to manipulate the string to the left of the "assets/" sub-folder, without necessarily knowing the format? Here are some examples :

```
<img src="./assets/123/pig.jpg" />
<img src="http://mysite.blah/assets/123/pig.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.mysite.blah/assets/123/pig.jpg" />
<img src='assets/123/pig.jpg' />
```

in css / inline styles :

```
background-image : URL('assets/123/pig.jpg')
background-image : URL(http://www.mysite.blah/assets/123/pig.jpg)
```

anyway, I think you get the picture. I essentially want to be able to look to the "left" of the word "assets" until I can find the logical start point of the url and then manipulate it from there to point to my CDN.

[image]

I'm not sure this is possible in regex, so any suggestions using a combination of regex / c# /HTML Agility Pack are welcome

Comment: You have written `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` twice. It wont solve anything, it just bugs me..

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you. Do you mean like [this](https://regex101.com/r/IwHWCJ/1)?

Comment: @Olian04 - It's just a typo ( RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ), maybe I should leave it there to bug you forever... LOL :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

`(?<BeforeAssets>.*?(?:\/|^))assets\/(?<AfterAssets>[A-Za-z0-9\-_\/.]+)\.(?<FileExtension>jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff|png|gif|js|css|mov|mp4|ogg|avi|mp3)`

You can try this out here: http://regexstorm.net/tester
Or here: https://regex101.com/r/b8XxcF/1

NB: In the above regex I escaped the forward slash characters. .Net doesn't require this, but doesn't complain; and doing so makes this compatible with other Regex engines; which means it can be tested on Regex101.

When testing with those tools you'll need to specify the `MultiLine` or `SingleLine` options to get the example where `assets/` has nothing preceding it, since otherwise the `^` character won't match the start of that line.  This option may not be required in your code; i.e. if you're only matching one string at a time, rather than a whole block of text.

---

**Update**

Apologies for misreading; you're parsing the full HTML page; not just the URIs returned from that page.  To do this you could use something like:

`["'\(](?<BeforeAssets>[^"'\(\)]*?)assets\/(?<AfterAssets>[A-Za-z0-9\-_\/.]+)\.(?<FileExtension>jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff|png|gif|js|css|mov|mp4|ogg|avi|mp3)`

(thankfully characters `"`, `'`, and `(` are illegal in the URL, so should be OK to detect the start of a variable: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2.)

This isn't fool-proof; it's better to use an HTML parsing tool, then pull out the URIs from that; but if you are doing everything with regex, hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thanks John, but I couldn't get that to work. I do use regex101 to test so smacked your example in there and nothing matched? as the source you can literally use the source of any web page and then change one of the image links to the example image above

Comment: Ah sorry; I'd assumed you were extracting the URIs from the links, then using them.  You're after something which finds links anywhere in the HTML code.  Will amend...

Comment: You're a legend!